# how to sort a printed out list by DESC

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm printing out a list of users that have answered questions asked by company:

```
<% @applications.all.each do |application| %>
<% application.answers.each do |answer| %>

  <p>Your question1: <%= answer.application.question_1 %></p>
  <p>Their answer 1: <%= answer.answer_1 %></p>
  <p>Your question 2: <%= answer.application.question_2 %></p>
  <p>Their answer 3: <%= answer.answer_2 %></p>
  <p>Your question 3: <%= answer.application.question_3 %></p>
  <p>Their answer 3: <%= answer.answer_3 %></p>


  <i>Answered by <b><%= link_to "#{answer.user.fullname}", user_path(answer.user.slug) %></b>, <%= time_ago_in_words(answer.created_at) %> ago</i> | <%= button_to "delete this applicant", root_url, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?"}, method: :delete %>
  <hr>
```

problem now is that they aren't in any specific order. I would like to sort 'created_at DESC' but haven't been able to successfully do so. Do I do it in the view, or in the model? What's recommended here and how do I do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this sort of thing in the controller's method that returns your page, ex: `index`:

```
@applications = Application.all.order("created_at DESC")
```

If you want to further organize your logic, you can start defining [scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) in your model and then use them in your controller.

Do not define anything other than basic conditional view logic in your views.